# select inner join, group_concat of sql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drop-down-menu

I have the following query:

```
$myquery = mysql_query("SELECT p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(m.name) as products
                    FROM access as pm
                    INNER JOIN seller as p on p.id = pm.id_seller
                    INNER JOIN products as m on m.id  = pm.id_product
                    WHERE p.id = '".$_COOKIE['id_seller']."'");
```

Which returns me this array:

```
Array (
[0] => Seller Name [name] => Seller Name
[1] => Product1 [products] => Product1
);
```

How should I query the database correctly? Thanking in consideration that I have 3 tables (products, access and seller). What I'd like to achieve is to attribute (access) one or more products to a seller.

And how my drop-down list populate code would look like?

```
<?php
      echo'<select name="productaccess">';
foreach($myquery as $product) {
      echo'<option value="'.$product.'">'.$product.'</option>';
}
      echo'</select>';
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the products for just *one* seller, you don't need grouping at all. Just list the names of the products:

```
$myquery = mysql_query("SELECT m.name
                    FROM access as pm
                    INNER JOIN seller as p on p.id = pm.id_seller
                    INNER JOIN products as m on m.id  = pm.id_product
                    WHERE p.id = '".$_COOKIE['id_seller']."'");
```

Now `$myquery` is only a resource identifier, not the results, so you get the latter with `mysql_fetch_array()` like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($myquery)) {
    echo'<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT is used with a GROUP BY clause, which is not present.  Add a 'GROUP BY p.name' to your SQL.  That will make the above SQL return a single row, with the seller name and the product names, separated by commas.  Then burst the product names into an array, which you then feed to the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still isn't working... :( Any clue what might be?